# JQuery - Firing a function by tabbing off of a specific textbox (losing focus from tab key)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to run some specific javascript code when the user hits the tab key to go to the next element on a certain text box.  To put this in perspective, this would create a new line of input if the user tabs off of the last element in the row... making it fast to enter lots of List type information.

Html:

```
<input value="normal tab" />
<input value="normal tab" />
<input value="this tab should fire function when tabbed off of" class="tab-makes-new-row" />
```

Javascript:

```
$('.tab-makes-new-row').on('focusout', function (e) {
         $(window).keyup(function (e) {
        var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
        if (code == 9) {
           alert('I was tabbed!');
        }
    });
});
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/2cvxqzLt/1/

The problem is, it will fire the alert when tabbing off of any textbox.  I want the alert to fire only when tabbing off of the input with the `.tab-makes-new-row` class.  What am I doing wrong?  Is it because the textbox is unfocused all the time unless focused?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're adding an event handler within the handling of an event, and the second one isn't filtered. (It'll also get re-registered multiple times, and won't necessarily fire for the event when the user tabbed out cross-browser.)

Your current approach will be **very** hard to get right. Instead, I suggest having a small `+` button just after that input, and adding the row when that `+` button gets focus. That way, tabbing out of the input will give focus to the `+` button, and you'll add the new row.

Something along these lines:

```js
var inputs =
    '<div>' +
        '<input value="normal tab" />' +
        '<input value="normal tab" />' +
        '<input value="last one" />' +
        '<input type="button" value="+" class="new-row" />' +
    '</div>';

function addRow() {
    // Add the inputs, focus the first one
    $(inputs).appendTo("#the-form")
             .find("input")[0]
             .focus();
}

// Delegated handler for focus on the `+` button
$("#the-form").on("focus", ".new-row", function() {
    // Remove the button
    $(this).remove();
    
    // Add a new row
    addRow();
});

// Add the first row
addRow();
```

```html
<form id="the-form">
</form>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Obviously, you can use CSS to make the button look however you want it to look, but it's useful to have *something* there to focus — and for the user to see.

Comment: That's really clever.  I like having the option to click the button, as well.  I'm going to go with this.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to combine events to make sure you are monitoring the `blur` event when the `keydown` event happens.

```
$('.tab-makes-new-row').on('keydown blur', function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 9) {
       alert('I was tabbed!');
    }
});
```

Answer (score -2):

Is this the correct solution? It fires when the input gets focused and not unfocused:

I replace `$(window)` with `$(this)` so it refers to the input you want.

```js
   $('.tab-makes-new-row').keydown(function (e) {
        var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
        if (code == 9) {
           alert('I was tabbed!');
        }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input value="normal tab" />
<input value="normal tab" />
<input value="this tab should fire function when tabbed off of" class="tab-makes-new-row" />
```

Comment: This seems to fire when it gets focus, not when it loses focus.

Comment: I updated the code. Try that. It was also creating multiple keyup events because the events were nested. I removed the focusout event and changed the keyup event to keydown, as the keydown event gets triggered (logically) when the input is tabbed, not after it is tabbed.